# Regex Headache, String formatting, datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, regex, datagrid, string-formatting

I've been battling it out for hours and admit defeat. I have coded a C# Win forms client which receives Telnet data in the following format:

```
Decimal  AlphaNum       Int "dB" Int "WPM" AN          Int + "Z"
14048.4  XY3CVI           19 dB  29 WPM                1700Z
14092.6  XY3CVI           19 dB  29 WPM    XZ          1700Z
```

Periodically due to an upstream bottleneck I get a 'double-hit' without the CRLF.

```
14048.4  XY3CVI           19 dB  29 WPM                1700Z14048.4  XY3CVI           19 dB  29 WPM                1700Z
```

The incoming data is padded with whitespace which vary in order to keep the columns aligned perfectly (by the server, not me)(accounting for varying numbers of characters in 'AlphaNum' and 'Int' which precedes dB.

I need a means - not necessarily regex, to add the CRLF when a string comes in doubled-up (sometimes tripled), preserving the extra data.

Since I'm already pleading for help I'd just as well go the whole hog, as it's likely the combined solution will be more elegant to implement as one:

To take the above 'problem', and format it for entry into a datagrid with four columns; from the above; columns 1, 2, 3 and 5. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `due to an upstream bottleneck` ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, your lines with the CRLF are always the same size right ?

Just check the size of every line, if it's longer than the expected size, just add the CRLF to the line using `line.Insert(expectedLineSize,"\r\n")`, you will then have a new line to check, just continue on like that until you don't have anymore lines.

As for the second part, you have fixed size columns, just use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)